# Cómo filtrar datos con FILTER() con varias condiciones OR en Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-hoja-de-cálculo, filtro, operador

En Google Sheets o en Excel, cuando usamos la [fórmula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=es) `FILTER(intervalo; condición1; [condición2; ...])`, todas los criterios o condiciones de la fórmula se tienen que cumplir.

Por ejemplo, aquí se filtrarán lo datos que sean **rojos y azules** (AND)

```
=FILTER(A1:B10;A1:A10="rojo";A1:A10="azul")
```

Pero quiero filtrar los datos que cumplan cualquiera de las 2 condiciones: **rojos o azules** (OR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez conoces el truco es bastante fácil de hacer. Utilizamos "+" en lugar de ";" si queremos la lógica OR.

```
=FILTER(A1:B10;(A1:A10="rojo")+(A1:A10="azul"))
```